"Погода в доме" - при чём тут зонт?
Мой вопрос о песне Ларисы Долиной "Погода в доме". Пытаясь понять её, я никак не возьму в толк, при чём тут зонт. Ведь погода в доме - это не температура и влажность воздуха в помещении, а чувства, настроение, гармония обитателей этого дома.
Когда поётся про "прогноз", имеется в виду, с каким настроением сегодня проснётся твой сожитель, какой смысл будет вкладывать в свои слова. Дожди, туман, извержение вулкана - здесь тоже имеется в виду, будет ли сожитель сердиться, нервничать, волноваться, рвать и метать.
И конечно, главней всего погода в доме. Всё остальное - суета. Есть я и ты, а всё, что кроме - легко уладить с помощью ... зонта???
Как зонт поможет уладить отношения? Мне кажется, тут лучше всего здесь уладить с помощью замка: есть я и ты, и мы с тобой вместе сможем разобраться в наших отношениях, для этого нам нужно отстраниться от всего, что кроме. И поэтому мы закроем дом на замок.
Только так я вижу логику.
Так при чём же тут зонт?

Замок — закрытие, отгороженность от мира, а зонт говорит о том, что эти внешние факторы будут, но с ним их легче перенести, и они не повлияют на "погоду в доме".

Интересный вопрос. Я задал ваш вопрос GPT чату, и вот, что он ответил.
В песне Ларисы Долиной "Погода в доме" зонт — это, скорее всего, метафора. В отличие от замка, который символизировал бы изоляцию от внешнего мира, зонт может быть символом защиты. Он, как предмет, не помогает решать проблемы напрямую, но служит защитой от внешних негативных воздействий — дождя, непогоды, того самого "суетного", что происходит вокруг. То есть зонт как бы укрывает от внешних конфликтов, негатива, обид, создавая личное пространство, где есть "я и ты".
Зонт в данном контексте можно интерпретировать как символ внутреннего спокойствия и сохранения гармонии, несмотря на «дожди» и «бури» вокруг, которые могут быть не только буквальными, но и эмоциональными или житейскими. Фраза "всё остальное — суета" намекает, что важнее всего отношения между близкими людьми, а не внешние обстоятельства.
Так что зонт — это не инструмент для решения проблем, а для того, чтобы минимизировать их влияние на "погоду в доме". С его помощью вы не даете внешнему миру разрушить гармонию внутри. Таким образом, метафора зонта добавляет к идее песне защитный аспект: мы можем защитить наш уютный мир от внешних бурь. 
